# Should you add an hyphen with un + foreign word?

Tags: style, orthography

I'm aware that you should add an hyphen in *un-American* and not add a hyphen in *unstylish.*

How about when it's a foreign word and, therefore, you're creating a new usage?

> Talking to my parents is the only *un-hikikomori* part of me.

Note: hikikomori is a Japanese word meaning recluse.

Comment: Just a personal opinion (obviously there are no absolute rules governing how such "hybrid portmanteau" words should be constructed), but I don't think ***un-*** is the best prefix here. I'd use ***non-*** (with hyphen, and probably "scare quotes" as well, cos *it ain't English!*).

Comment: ...I suspect the only reason we *usually* (but [not always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unBritish%2Cun-British%2Cunbritish%2Cun-british&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)) hyphenate *un-American, un-British* is just that we don't like the look of the bare "CamelCase" format in this context, where the thing being negated positively ***demands*** capitalisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do need the hyphen.

Although "un-" is a recognised prefix, words like *undo*, *unstylish* etc are words in their own right and appear in the dictionary. The flexibility of English means that we often do make new words with recognisable prefixes, but when you add "un-" to a word in order to negate it, you really do need the hyphen otherwise the new word might not be recognisable.

An added problem with prefixing a proper noun is that you can't capitalise it unless you hyphenate (ie you can't write "un**A**merican").

Even more so with your example - you want to put an English prefix onto Japanese word! Many English speakers would not realise that it had a prefix unless they were already very familiar with the original Japanese word. They wouldn't recognise that you had added the prefix and would wonder what "unhikikomori" meant.

If a compound word it isn't in the dictionary, as a rule of thumb, hyphenate it.